# How to access Admin details in Laravel 5.2 Multi Auth

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am a beginner in Laravel; Please help me to fix this.

**Code for accessing user info** This code is working for user

```
{{ Auth::guard('web')->user()->first_name . ' ' . Auth::guard('web')->user()->last_name }}
```

**Code I am using for accessing admin info** This code not working

```
{{ Auth::guard('admin')->admin()->first_name . ' ' . Auth::guard('admin')->admin()->last_name }}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I got the answer

```
{{ Auth::guard('admin')->user()->first_name . ' ' . Auth::guard('admin')->user()->last_name }}
```